# Generic method to get id's from either a single object or collection

Tags: ruby

I want to make a generic method that will take either a single object or collection, and then return an array of id's, and the actual id to take from the object/collection will also be passed in as a parameter.

Example:

```
a = []
a << get_ids("car_id", some_object)
a << get_ids("user_id", some_collection)


def self.get_ids(id_name, obj)
  # ??
end
```

This needs metaprogramming I know, but how do I figure out if its a collection or not?
do I send a message to check if "id_name" is a property?

Also, I currently need this type of functionality, so I thought of making it generic so I can re-use it.   Does it have any major performance implications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def self.get_ids(id_name, obj)
  if obj.is_a? Enumerable
    obj.collect {|e| e.send(id_name) }
  else
    obj.send(id_name)
  end
end
```

Alternatively,

```
def self.get_ids(id_name, *objs)
  objs.collect {|e| e.send(id_name) }
end
...
a << get_ids("car_id", some_object)
a << get_ids("user_id", *some_collection)
```

Comment: Does the * mean you can enter multiple objects?

Comment: Yes, [read this](http://endofline.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/the-strange-ruby-splat/).

Comment: +1 But what if `obj` is an Enumerable and understands `id_name`? The question seems ambiguous on this point.

Comment: @jtbandes how could I create a stub object and/or collection to test this?  (that has an id_xxx property)

Comment: @Blankman: What if `obj` is an Enumerable (i.e. something the looks like a collection) but also responds to an `id_name` call? Do you treat it as a collection and look inside it or do you just return `[obj.send(id_name)]`?

Comment: I see, hmm...not sure, in my case I am passing a model or a collection of models.  but since its a generic method I guess I should assume that.  not sure!